# What is a Visionary Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Visionary Phrase™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| VISIONARY PHRASES | NOT VISIONARY PHRASES |
| --- | --- |
| WHEN SOME WHIR | ONCE MANY PURR |
| LUST THEN SNOG | SHAG OVER PINE |
| SOME BOLD JAZZ | ANY OLD POP |
| BREW NEAR OVEN | STEEP ABOVE STOVE |
| MINER BURNT LOWRY | DIGGER SPOILT TURNER |
| KILL HIS DATE | SLAY HER BEAU |
| VOGUE TOFU CABAL | POSH VEGAN SECT |
| FETAL RALPH WEEPS | BENT JOHN SOBS |
| COTTON TIGHTS RUNOFF | SILKEN SHORTS SPILLAGE |
| SAUCE OR GRITS | GRAVY AND QUESO |
| OTTO PENS BLUE | JESS JOTS GREY |
| BLUNT BAKER CLERK | CURT BUTCHER HELP |
| PINK SWAN DON | GREY SHOE SUE |
| THE WEAK PLED | FEW ABLE HID |
| STEAM THREE BONES | BOIL FOUR LEGS |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
VISIONARY PHRASES,      NOT VISIONARY PHRASES
WHEN SOME WHIR,         ONCE MANY PURR
LUST THEN SNOG,         SHAG OVER PINE
SOME BOLD JAZZ,         ANY OLD POP
BREW NEAR OVEN,         STEEP ABOVE STOVE
MINER BURNT LOWRY,      DIGGER SPOILT TURNER
KILL HIS DATE,          SLAY HER BEAU
VOGUE TOFU CABAL,       POSH VEGAN SECT
FETAL RALPH WEEPS,      BENT JOHN SOBS
COTTON TIGHTS RUNOFF,   SILKEN SHORTS SPILLAGE
SAUCE OR GRITS,         GRAVY AND QUESO
OTTO PENS BLUE,         JESS JOTS GREY
BLUNT BAKER CLERK,      CURT BUTCHER HELP
PINK SWAN DON,          GREY SHOE SUE
THE WEAK PLED,          FEW ABLE HID
STEAM THREE BONES,      BOIL FOUR LEGS
```

Hint 1:

> The following are also Visionary Phrases: [image]

Hint 2:

> If you've been focusing on formal properties of these phrases, I would suggest shifting to something else; you can also *try* thinking along the lines of meanings and etymologies.

Hint 3:

> Focusing on the first letter should help.

Hint 4:

> Hints 2 and 3 are playfully ambiguous.

Hint 5:

> Focusing on 'A' should help. In particular, look for a pattern.

Comment: we're gonna need a bigger hint

Comment: I've been working at this one, but getting nowhere.  Hint 4 is not very helpful, and in fact specifically calls into question how helpful Hints 2 and 3 have been.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation, maybe I've been being too playful in my hints. I added a fairly straightforward one.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation and a bounty

Comment: This was the first puzzle I looked at when I started using this stack.  I guess now I don't have to feel so stupid for not getting it within 60 minutes as some people on this site tend to do, lol.

Comment: @tilper Same there. I'm on this one since day one, still can't figure what is hidden there.

Comment: @tilper 60 minutes? Pfft, amateurs. 60 *seconds* is what I call a fast solving time :-P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I'm onto something here ...

> The original version of this solution included a lot of unnecessary (but not incorrect) arithmetic. As @Arth suggested, the calculations added up to a [Vigenère Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher). The three words in each Visionary Phrase™ correspond to the ciphered text, plain text and key, in some order.

WHEN SOME WHIR

> Using `SOME` as the ciphered text and `WHEN` as the key, the plain text is `WHIR`.

LUST THEN SNOG

> Here, `LUST` is the ciphered text, `THEN` is the key, revealing `SNOG` as the plain text.

SOME BOLD JAZZ

> `BOLD` is ciphered, `SOME` is the key, and `JAZZ` is the result.

...

PINK SWAN DON

> Due to the nature of the cipher, it's not possible for the plain text and cipher text to have different lengths. The outlying word must be the key. In this case `DON` must be the key, which transforms a ciphered `SWAN` into `PINK`.

Those designated as a Non Visionary Phrase™ do not enjoy this relationship.

> It's also worth noting that if you squint really hard, Visionary looks like Vigenère, and even shares some sounds.

Comment: This is known as a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) (sounds a bit like Visionary). Visionary Phrases seem to have the property whereby the first word encrypted with a Vignère cipher, using the third word as the key, gives the second word. Excellent work!

Comment: I am familiar with such a cipher. I cannot for the life of me think of a reason why I didn't see it's application here. Whoops.

Comment: I thought you might be! I just wanted everyone to know I'd spotted the clue in the title (after reading your answer of course) ;)

Comment: Just noticed that some of the phrases appear to use the second word as the key to generate the third word.

Comment: Many of them are 1'st being phrase, 2nd being key and 3rd the result.. 1'st being phrase, 3rd being key and 2'nd the result

Comment: Excellent work! I didn't include the `cipher` tag since I knew it was possible to notice the property without specific knowledge of the cipher. Knowing the cipher is only necessary to make sense of the name: These phrases are *Vigenere-y*, pronounced an awful lot like *visionary* (but with a long *i*).

Comment: By the way, I hinted at this property by telling puzzlers to "try shifting to something else" in Hint 2.

Comment: Honestly, I started doing that because I noticed that they were all 3 words, and most phrases included words that were all the same length.

Comment: Why was it originally called a Blaze Phrase?

Comment: Yeah, at first I only used keys that were the same length as the plaintext and ciphertext but I could find enough phrases so I starte using smaller keys. Plus, I knew the property would be noticed even using the smaller keys, although it's harder to see.

Comment: @MikeQ, after [him](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_de_Vigenère)

Comment: @Matt, I will award you the bounty if you generalize your answer to cover cases like "Pink swan don", which don't fit your explanation (since you mention a specific order of words). If you want, you can just explain what a Vigenere cipher is and show how it works for a few of them...

Comment: @Silenus I hope my edits are satisfactory.

Comment: They are! The bounty is yours (in T minus 19 hours).